# Find cost of call at disconnect? *Twilio API*

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to get the amount spent on a twilio call at the end of that call using the twilio API?

Comment: Did my answer fixed your issue?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes.

You can execute a script at the end of the call. You can find the cost of that call in this script.

- If you are using REST API, then specify a `StatusCallback` URL and that script will be executed at the end of the call. (Refer [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) for more details)
- If you are using `Dial` TwiML to make calls, specify an `action` parameter. (Refer [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action) for more details)

Now in this url, you will get the Sid of the dialed call as a parameter. Using this call sid, you can make a REST API request to get the details of that particular call.

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library
$sid = "{{ACC SID}}"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$call_sid = $_REQUEST['DialCallSid']; //if you are using dial
//*************** OR *************
$call_sid = $_REQUEST['CallSid']; //if you are using REST API

//Get the details of the call using rest API from the call_sid
$call = $client->account->calls->get($call_sid);

$price = $call->Price; //get the cost of the call
$price_usit = $call->PriceUnit; // get the currency in cost is charged

?>
```

Please note that twilio might take some time to populate these values. So if you are not getting the correct values, please try to put a sleep before requesting call resource.

Comment: Here is the error I got: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Services_Twilio_Rest_Call as array` and is giving that error at the code that says `$price = $call['Price'];`

Comment: Please try `$call->Price`

Comment: Consider accepting my answer by ticking on it if this solved your issue.